# Getting output as [object Object] even after entering proper code

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

https://stackoverflow.com/q/74336134/19674753

Please refer the above link to read my question. Apologies, I posted my query by mistake in stack overflow instead of Salesforce stack exchange.

Please help me asap.it will be of great help.

Comment: @Derek F, can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably trying to show you an error, but the error is an object so no clear output appears.

This can be because of lack of permission on the field Picture__c for example, or not access to Contact object.

Try to put a console log and open the browser inspector to check what happens:

```
@wire(getContactList)
wiredContacts({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        this.contacts = data;
        this.error = undefined;
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
        console.log(error)
        this.contacts = undefined;
    }
}
```

Check that I added a console.log below 'this.error'.

Another option is to assign this.error to the body of the message:

```
this.error = error.body.message;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I figured out the issue. I had forgot to mention cacheable= true inside AuraEnabled notation. Thanks for the response anyway